# service not start, Format version is not supported error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cratedb

i'm using [CrateDB](https://crate.io/) (ElsaticSearch clone) and worked fine in long time and rebooted os before, but after reboot OS yesterday, service crate not started
before worked fine.
i can't find any document for fix this problem
service not started `org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service` and have error `Format version is not supported` 
can anyone help me please?

```
2022-01-09T10:52:34,421][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Oberalpstock] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda2)]], net usable_space [20.3gb], net total_space [39.1gb], types [ext4]
[2022-01-09T10:52:34,435][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Oberalpstock] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2022-01-09T10:52:34,937][ERROR][o.e.b.BootstrapProxy     ] [Oberalpstock] Exception
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:651) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:53) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:266) [crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) [crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.execute(CrateDB.java:138) [crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:81) [crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) [crate-cli.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [crate-cli.jar:?]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:91) [crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:84) [crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/lib/crate/nodes/0/_state/segments_zm"))): 0 (needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 6.0 and later.
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:307) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:291) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:61) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:58) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:720) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:81) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.PersistedClusterStateService.nodeMetadata(PersistedClusterStateService.java:266) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadNodeMetadata(NodeEnvironment.java:416) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:329) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:270) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
[2022-01-09T10:52:34,979][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [Oberalpstock] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupExceptionProxy.<init>(StartupExceptionProxy.java:30) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:162) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.execute(CrateDB.java:138) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:81) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[crate-cli.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[crate-cli.jar:?]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:91) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.main(CrateDB.java:84) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to bind service
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:651) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:53) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:266) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/lib/crate/nodes/0/_state/segments_zm"))): 0 (needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 6.0 and later.
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:307) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:291) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:61) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:58) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:720) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:81) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:63) ~[lucene-core-8.8.2.jar:8.8.2 a92a05e195b775b30ca410bc0a26e8e79e7b3bfb - mdrob - 2021-04-06 16:33:27]
    at org.elasticsearch.gateway.PersistedClusterStateService.nodeMetadata(PersistedClusterStateService.java:266) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadNodeMetadata(NodeEnvironment.java:416) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:329) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:270) ~[crate-server.jar:?]
    at io.crate.node.CrateNode.<init>(CrateNode.java:53) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy$1.<init>(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.setup(BootstrapProxy.java:192) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapProxy.init(BootstrapProxy.java:266) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    at io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB.init(CrateDB.java:158) ~[crate-app.jar:4.6.1]
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Did you update CrateDB to a newer version? Not entirely clear what "long time" really is?

Comment: Looks like that file got corrupted. If your data is replicated on other nodes you can just recreate the node or clean up `/var/lib/crate` otherwise you'll have to restore snapshot or reindex.